# Create a list of lists for each possible one-change-alteration of a list

Tags: haskell

I am sorry for not being able to really formulate this question well in the title; I have already asked the same question about triples and have decided to opt for a list after all, so here is the explanation. Thank you for the patience and great help received here!

I need to create a function that is capable of doing the following, yet am quite a newby to Haskell and find myself in need of passing states that is just not in the functional paradigm (nor do I want a semi imperative solution, I just want to know how to do it the functional way). The functionality is as follows:

```
specialFunc :: [a] -> a -> [[a]]
specialFunc [1,2,3] 0
=> [[0,2,3],[1,0,3],[1,2,0]]
```

I am trying to create the function by mapping over the list supplied as an argument, but find myself at a loss when I try and figure out how to replace a specific value, add the resulting list to the results and continue working with the next item but with the original list (if that makes sense). Any help is definitely welcome, thank you!

Comment: What did you try, what is not working with that?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem My initial thought was using `zip [0..]` to enumerate the items, using a helper function `specialFunc'` that is mapped over the list and in that function using the index to concatenate all items before the index, the item that needs to be inserted and all items after the index. However, that feels a bit of a weird way to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define this in a recursive way. If the list is empty (1), then you return an empty list, so `[]` maps to `[]`. If the list is non-empty (2), then we generate a list where the first item is the *tail* of the non-empty list, prepended with the value, and we recurse on the *tail* of the list, and need to prepend the head of the list.

So we can define a function that looks like:

```
specialFunc :: [a] -> a -> [[a]]
specialFunc xs x = go xs
    where go [] = …      -- (1)
          go (h:hs) = …  -- (2)
```

You can make use of [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) to prepend the value `h` to the lists you generate through recursion.

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helps!

Comment: Just so I understand correctly; the value h can have a length more than 1, right? In the given example with `[1,2,3]` as input we will need to prepend `[1,2]` for the final one, or am I mistaken? My code is now: `... where go []     = []
          go (h:hs) = (x:hs):go hs`.

Comment: You need to post-process the recursion, so `go hs` needs some extra processing, you need to prepend each sublist in `go hs` with `h` as first element.

Answer (score 0):

The solution, with many credits to @WillemVanOnsem:

```
specialFunc :: [a] -> a -> [[a]]
specialFunc xs x = go xs
    where go []     = []
          go (h:hs) = (x:hs): map (h:) (go hs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you another idea of how this could be done, you might turn on the `ParallelListComp` extension and zip up the result of `inits` and `tails` appropriately:

```
{-# Language ParallelListComp #-}
import Data.List
specialFunc xs x = [pre ++ [x] ++ suf | pre <- inits xs | _:suf <- tails xs]
```

The same idea can also be done without an extension, of course, though I think it's not quite as pretty:

```
import Data.List
specialFunc xs x = zipWith (\pre suf -> pre ++ [x] ++ suf) (inits xs) (tail (tails xs))
```